# Corona SDK. How to add lines to images

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want to add line to image directly without a groups to make the line rasterized object (instead of a vector). The fact is that due to the large number of vector objects ( over 100) application work slow.

Answer (score 0):

After drawing the lines, insert them to a group and convert them to a single display object using display.capture function

Have a look here http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/capture.html

Also take a look at 
[display.save](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/save.html)